# Eagle PCB design Libraries?

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, components

I am doing my first Eagle PCB design. It's been going smoothly so far, however, I just hit a road bump. I am using a TC1269 Regulator, but cannot find the CAD library for it. I have looked into tutorials to creating custom parts, but I was hoping that instead I would be able to find a premade one since the TC1269 employs a 8 pin MSOP package, which is common enough that there should be some CAD equivalents already out there.

Does anyone know perhaps another equivalent part that employs the same package that I can use in place of the TC1269 or perhaps a library with the 8 pin MSOP package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a set standard package libraries called ref-packages-* look into ref-packages-smd-ipc.lbr. I usually try to search for a part by using package name: in schematics editor press "add" and enter *msop* (with "*" at begining and at the end) into search field.

I can recommend SparkFun and Adafruit libraries - these can be trusted and usually contain most common packages. [This page](http://www.bobstarr.net/pages/downloads.html) has a set of decent libraries.

As regarding to devices it's usually faster to make your own than to look for them over the internet. If you download something you never know if you can trust them.

Answer (score -2):

If you can't find a component with a similar pad layout, why not do a 'handjob' if you are only going the need the layout infrequently.

When I say  I mean you simply layout pads in the appropriate configuration mabually. Many, many moons ago PCB layouts were done with sticky tape and pads stuck on mylar. Everything was a 'handjob'.

The only difference today is that we use computers.

Comment: This bad advice.  You're going to have to define the footprint at least once anyway.  You might as well do it in such a way to make it re-usable in the future.  Directly editing the footprint on a board circumvents all the useful checks modern software can do for you, and is a really bad thing to suggest to newbies to do.  They need to learn the right way, despite the desire for instant gratification.  Suggesting instant gratification is doing them a disservice, and this solution isn't any more instant than doing it right anyway.