# Eagle library for MCP2551

Tags: components, microchip, eaglecad, can, library

I need to make a PCB, and the only software I have is [EAGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAGLE_%28program%29). All the other parts are listed in my libraries, but where can I find a library that has [MCP2551](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010405) (CAN transceiver)?

Comment: Create any parts you're missing, use a [tutorial](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/110) to get you started.

Comment: Isn't that just a DIP8?

Comment: Which one do you have? The SMD or Lead version?

Comment: related: [Eagle PCB design Libraries?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56991/eagle-pcb-design-libraries)

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. He just need the eagle library which already exists

Comment: Do the element14 libs have it? They have tons of parts.

Answer (score 6):

There is one in my "Interface" library.  http://www.embedinc.com/pic/dload.htm

### Added:

I just refreshed the Eagle Tools release available from the above web page.  The previous version was from last November.  I'm pretty sure the MCP2551 would have been in the old version too, but it should definitely be there now.

Comment: He asked specifically for the eagle library containing the MCP2251 component. I don't think this answer is really related since it contains the full installation file for eagle with the standard libraries

Comment: Thanks a lot :D :D i am a newbie in electronics , i recently finished my mechatronics course :D

Comment: @Handoko: No, my Eagle Tools release contains no Eagle installation file and none of the Eagle standard libraries (I never use the Eagle standard libraries).  It contains a bunch of tools I have created to use with Eagle, and it also contains a bunch of libraries I have developed for Eagle.  As I said, there is a MCP2551 in the Interface library, which is one of the files included in the release.  I'm not going to create a separate release for every separate part of my Eagle toolchain I let other people use for free.

Comment: @Olin Oh, I see. Sorry when I looked at your link I got the impression it was a standard eagle installation. Good work creating these extensions then. I'll post something about your page on my blog :) does your extension work for eagle 6.5 as well? If yes, I'll download and install them on my laptop too.

Comment: @Hando: I currently use Eagle version 5.  I believe that version 6 can import version 5 files, which it then converts to the new version 6 XML format.  After that, you can't take the files back to version 5.  So yes, I think you can import my files into your version 6.

Comment: Thank you so much Olin for your eagle tools -- I definitely put some of them to good use.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version you have so I'll just post links with different versions.

For

[MCP2551-E/P](http://www.farnell.com/cad/1545489.zip)

[MCP2551-E/SN](http://www.farnell.com/cad/1545491.zip)

[MCP2551-I/P](http://www.farnell.com/cad/1638118.zip)

[MCP2551-I/SN](http://www.farnell.com/cad/1638319.zip)

[MCP2551T-I/SN](http://www.farnell.com/cad/1790658.zip)

Next time please tell some more about which component. (Mount type etc)

Source: farnell.com
I have you direct links to the files cuz farnell only wants registered people to download the files actually.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D :D i am a newbie in electronics , i recently finished my mechatronics course :D

Comment: No problem. Welcome to this site, and good luck with your project