# Zener diodes Eagle library

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, diodes, zener, library

I need to make a PCB, and the only software I have is [Eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAGLE_%28program%29). All the other parts are listed in my libraries, but where can I find a library that has [DIODES INC. - MMSZ5226BS](http://pt.farnell.com/diodes-inc/mmsz5226bs/diodo-zener-3-3v-0-2-w-sod323/dp/2061493) (Zener diode)?

Comment: If your library doesn't have a part, you make it yourself. Relying on third party libraries is terrible practice.

Comment: Farnell has Eagle files for all of its parts, doesn't it? It's just a matter of finding it. Maybe this post may give you some directions: [Eagle library for MCP2551](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/112992/29792).

Answer (score 2):

As Matt Young commented above, it's a good idea to learn how to make your own parts. It's really not that hard to make a new part in Eagle once you get the gist of it.

It's a 3 step process:

1. Create a schematic symbol. This is a generic symbol that might be used for any number of specific parts. For a zener diode, you would draw the standard symbol for a zener diode. You only have to make this symbol once for any number of zener diodes you use in the future.
2. Create the part package (PCB footprint). Your diode has a SOD-323 footprint. Again, you'd make the package generic because any number of future parts you make might use the SOD-323 footprint.
3. Create a component that ties the symbol to the package.

Sparkfun has a [great tutorial](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/110) on their website that steps you through all the details of creating a new part. Now, all of that said, Sparkfun also produces their own [Eagle libraries](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun-Eagle-Libraries) that happen to have a SOD-323 diode already available in the DiscreteSemi library.